# Transforming CSS with Pure JavaScript not Work

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-events

I tried to transform my div with javascript after getting element by IDs. But i got nothing, it doesn't works.

Here is my code :

```js
const sliderA = document.getElementById("obSlideTop1");
const sliderB = document.getElementById("obSlideTop2");
const flame = document.getElementById("THST");
flame.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  sliderA.style.transform = "translate(-3vw, -343vh);"

  sliderB.style.transform = "translate(3vw, -343vh);"
})
```

But when i tried to styling with something else like `.backgroundColor` or `.opacity`, it still works with them. `object.style.transform` is the only thing that have problem with me.

```js
const sliderA = document.getElementById("obSlideTop1");
const sliderB = document.getElementById("obSlideTop2");
const flame = document.getElementById("THST");
flame.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  sliderA.style.transform = "translate(-3vw, -343vh);"
  sliderA.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(124, 1, 124)";
  sliderA.style.opacity = ".5"

  sliderB.style.transform = "translate(3vw, -343vh);"
  sliderB.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(233, 33, 33)";
  sliderB.style.opacity = ".5";

  console.log(sliderA,sliderB)
})
```

it have console output :

```html
<div id="obSlideTop1" style="background-color: rgb(124, 1, 124); opacity: 0.5;"></div> 
<div id="obSlideTop2" style="background-color: rgb(233, 33, 33); opacity: 0.5;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `"translate(-3vw, -343vh);"` is an invalid value for a transform because of the semi-colon `;` inside of the string.

```js
const sliderA = document.getElementById("obSlideTop1");
const sliderB = document.getElementById("obSlideTop2");
const flame = document.getElementById("THST");
flame.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  sliderA.style.transform = "translate(-3vw, -343vh)";
  sliderA.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(124, 1, 124)";
  sliderA.style.opacity = ".5"

  sliderB.style.transform = "translate(3vw, -343vh)";
  sliderB.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(233, 33, 33)";
  sliderB.style.opacity = ".5";

  console.log(sliderA,sliderB)
})
```

```html
<div id="obSlideTop1" style="background-color: rgb(124, 1, 124); opacity: 0.5;"></div> 
<div id="obSlideTop2" style="background-color: rgb(233, 33, 33); opacity: 0.5;"></div>
<button id="THST">flame</button>
```

Comment: Woa, thanks! I didn't expected that semicolon will make it to be an invalid input. 